# How to use Animation nodes expression to call numpy.lcm?

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to write a blender / Animation nodes to generate [Epicycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicycloid) but I am getting an error message from the Expressions node.

The imports are `math`, `numpy` and the expression is `lcm(a,b)` but the error message is `ufunc 'lcm' d..ype('float64')`.

I assume "d..ype" is `dtype` but since I have tried both ints and floats as input and there is no `float64` how can I call the [numpy function](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lcm.html)?.

I am on a Windows 10 machine running blender 2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the modules name **math** to **numpy** in the *advanced node settings* of the [Expression Node](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/expression.html) which is located in the N-panel.

[image]

Comment: While your exact example does work for me, it produces the same error when variables (inputs) are substituted for the constants.

Comment: ![Error msg](https://s270.photobucket.com/user/ltattrie/media/Blender%20Animation%20Nodes/an_to_lcm.png.html?sort=3&o=0)

Comment: I think "lcm" does not take the float data, only integer values, https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/lcm

Comment: ![sucess](https://s270.photobucket.com/user/ltattrie/media/Blender%20Animation%20Nodes/an_to_lcm%20works.png.html?sort=3&o=0) It works. But I feel that I have tried this before and it did not work. What could have changed? I'm not sure. There might be the possibility that some errors in expression nodes cause things to be "remembered" from one expression to another (That is they are not Functional nodes). So my feeling is if there is an ongoing problem with an expression node delete the node and recreate it.

Comment: @punchcard It is working because now you are using integer variables. There is no problem with the Expression Node, the only thing is, numpy module "lcm" does not handle the float variables.